# In Androidstudio java class file showing as a text file in IDE

Tags: android-studio

I have ported my project from Eclipse to Android Studio.But my Application class "AppController.java" alone showing as a text file.I deleted the file and created again but getting following error message.

Unable to parse template "class"
Error message: Selected class file name mapped 'AppController.java' to not java file type 'Textfiles'

Note: I have double checked the file types but no luck. File->Settings->File Types the file type for Java source files, Java class files and Text files

Comment: I met with similar problem and answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57952900/9147392

Answer (score 21):

I have also encountered the same issue and from your suggestion went to File->Settings->File Types and saw the file name I am trying to create say xyz.java is registered in the "recognized file types" list. As soon as I deleted the entry from that list xyz.java is recognized properly.

Comment: Thanks. this solved my problem. Do you know how did this happened?

Comment: The reason is you maybe installed the 64 bit version on a 32 bit machine. I had the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Deleted the Android studio's ".AndroidStudio" In the following path from my system C:\Users\user.

Started the Android Studio and configured freshly. That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a source file and a library. I had to mark the root source directory as a source directory.

For example. Your class is: `com.example.test.TestFile.java` where the root folder is `java`. In `Android Studio`, right click on the `java folder` and select `Mark Directory as` --> `Sources root`. This was on Android Studio 2.2 and 2.3 for me.

My Intellisense was then able to pick up all the library references and give intellisense suggestions in my source file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Special file types are saved in Android studio's folder ".AndroidStudio[version]\filetypes.xml" (located at C:\Users[user] on Windows).

Close Android Studio, delete this file and open it again.

The IDE should reset to its default file types values.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file -> Override File Type -> select the type it was before.

[image]