# Android Studio is not building complete files

Tags: android, android-studio-3.2

Whenever I make new project, android studio does not build colors.xml file completely.
colors.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
<component name="AndroidLayouts">
    <shared>
        <config />
    </shared>
</component>
<component name="CMakeSettings">
    <configuratio
```

Obviously, android studio is giving the error given below:
Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Comment: Same issue?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52782150/4409113 reinstalling android studio might help? It uses `UTF-8` format, so check my answer in the provided link.

Comment: project encoding is already set to system default. Is reinstalling android studio the only solution? it is so much time taking.

Comment: Update it or reinstall it. Then it will work fine. Remember **not to import the old configuration**. No, I don't think if that would take much time.

Comment: changed global encoding to system default but getting the same error.

Comment: My internet is too slow.. downloading sdks after installation takes too much time :D

Comment: No. You don’t need to download the SDK again if they’re seperated (not using bundle) from the Android Studio.

Comment: can you please add some links for detailed information about this shifting of sdks?

Comment: It's simple. There are just Android SDK manager with the Android Studio and both in an installable called bundle. But, it depends which one you're using. Anyhow, you won't need to download the sdk packages for the Android Studio reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well-formed. In general, this error indicates that something is wrong with the range of the start and end tags.

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

              <component android:name="AndroidLayouts">
                 <shared>
                   <config />
                 </shared>
             </component>

            </set>
```

Comment: **android studio does not build colors.xml file completely. colors.xml file is:** ...

Comment: I know this is not well formed. But my question is why android studio is not auto-completing the file while making new project?